# Skeleton and number of columns

Tags: css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm trying to use [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) for my next project, but I can't really figure out whether it's as simplistic as it seems to me.

Am I right in thinking that the only thing it does out-of-the-box is stack columns on top of each other when the browser width reaches a specific breakpoint?

Is there no way to say "this column has 25% width when >800px, 50% when >600px and 100% when <=600px"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that the only thing it does out-of-the-box is stack columns on top of each other when the browser width reaches a specific breakpoint?

it is exactly that, if you want it to have any other functionality you need to add your own css after skeleton.css has been declared.
It is a very simple css framework that is meant to be customized by the person using it.

IF you look in the css file right at the bottom you will see the following code:

```
        /* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

this is where you can add your custom css for the different screen sizes.